# Scikit-learn: is semi-supervised Naive Bayes implementation available?

Tags: python, classification, bayesian, scikit-learn, bayesian-networks

I would like to use the implementation of Semi-supervised Naive Bayes (Bernoulli) of Scikit-learn. According to [this link in github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/430/files), there was some work and discussion about it one year ago (class SemisupervisedNB). On the other hand, there seems to be [another different implementation (function fit_semi?) which seems it was polished by another user afterwards](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/107). However none of them are available in the current stable release.

Could someone show me an example on how could I use one of these two implementations with the current release of scikit-learn in order to build a Semisupervised Naive Bayes ? Thanks.

P.S.: I am using scikit-learn classifiers from NLTK with the class SklearnClassifier

**EDIT**

I have tried the code of SemiSupervisedNB in my project changing the label for the unlabeled class from -1 to 2 (I am using SKlearnClassifier from NLTK and my unlabeled class gets the label 2). However, I am getting ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs when computing d (difference between current and previous params of the model) because the intercept arrays contain inf values... Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: You can try to check out the branch and work on that, but I'm not sure it is in a good state currently - also it is quite behind the current stable. You could try to rebase / merge the branch onto current master. But if you are not familiar with git / the project, you will probably have some issues. Or just wait on @larsmans to comment and tell you what to do ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I don't have much time for reviewing code now... I'll  wait for @ogrisel as well  :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't have time to fix this up or even instruct you how to do it. The semi-supervised NB should work (a colleague tried just a few months ago) but doesn't tie in with current scikit-learn at all. You could try rebasing it, as @amueller suggested.

Comment: @AM2 Some months ago I opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1310) about this topic. I found a way to get the implementation of `SemiSupervisedNB` working. However, I haven't tested so far whether the described changes to the master branch affect other classifiers or code. Try it with caution!

Comment: @Peter Stahl Thanks. I have tried the code of SemiSupervisedNB in my project changing the label for the unlabeled class from -1 to 2 (I am using SKlearnClassifier from NLTK and my unlabeled class gets the label 2). However, I am getting ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs when computing d (difference between current and previous params of the model) because the intercept arrays contain inf values... Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: @AM2 Do you just use the emnb branch of @larsmans' fork? Or did you copy the class `SemiSupervisedNB` to the current master branch? You also have to copy the class `LabelBinarizer` from `sklearn/preprocessing/__init__.py` to `sklearn/preprocessing.py` and replace the class with the same name in the latter file. Please read the issue on GitHub more carefully. Then it should be clear I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some months ago, I opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1310) about this topic. It is possible to add the respective code to the current master branch of scikit-learn.

The user @larsmans added an experimental class `SemisupervisedNB` to the file `sklearn/naive_bayes.py` around a year ago. This code resides in the branch `emnb` of his forked scikit-learn repository and can be accessed [here](https://github.com/larsmans/scikit-learn/tree/emnb).

The essential code resides in two files:

1. The file `naive_bayes.py` in the current master branch has to be replaced by the older one from the `emnb` branch.
2. An editing of the class `LabelBinarizer` is necessary which can be found in the file `sklearn/preprocessing.py` in the master branch. The entire class has to be replaced by its definition in @larsmans' `emnb` branch. There, it resides in the file `sklearn/preprocessing/__init__.py`.

Even though the code for the Naive Bayes classifiers have not changed a lot for a year, some bug fixes were added to them. Therefore it makes sense to keep the current versions of the file `naive_bayes.py` and the class `LabelBinarizer` and instead to give the experimental versions different names.

I've just created my own fork of the scikit-learn repository and added the experimental files on top of the current stable branch `0.13.X`. This branch is called `0.13.X-emnb` and can be accessed [here](https://github.com/pemistahl/scikit-learn/tree/0.13.X-emnb). If you look at my three recent commits ([1](https://github.com/pemistahl/scikit-learn/commit/9beea6bb51b847c1f33fb56870101b0796130f2f) and [2](https://github.com/pemistahl/scikit-learn/commit/547e4f58f9e39d72f81cb3d53b95fe165570ef55) and [3](https://github.com/pemistahl/scikit-learn/commit/f85d76c602f4f13ca9a0702415e49d35d09b2cdf)), you see which files I've changed and newly created.

Since `SemisupervisedNB` does not work together with the most recent versions of the other classifiers, I've just added a new module next to `naive_bayes.py` called `semisupervised_naive_bayes.py`. In there, you find the older versions of the classifiers in renamed versions, e.g. `SemiMultinomialNB` instead of `MultinomialNB` so that they don't clash with the most recent versions of the classifiers. Likewise, I've added a class `SemisupervisedLabelBinarizer` next to `LabelBinarizer` (the choice of the name is a bit unfortunate but at least it's clear what it should be used for).

So, if you want to use the semisupervised versions of the classifiers, use the module `sklearn.semisupervised_naive_bayes`. For the current versions, use the module `sklearn.naive_bayes`.

But please keep in mind that this is highly experimental. It's just a setting for getting this old code working. I haven't searched for bugs.

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience, finally got it running with the current branch. I had to change lines 501 and 448  of semisupervised_naive_bayes.py to "SemiBaseDiscreteNB" and "SemiBernoulliNB" respectively.

Comment: @AM2 No problem. You're welcome. :) I need the semisupervised version myself, that's why I've dealt with this issue in so much detail. I'm glad that I could help.

Comment: @AM2 Oh I see, I've changed the class names in the two forgotten lines 448 and 501. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Thanks again! I modified NLTK's SKlearnClassifier in order to use this classifier. When running it with relabel_all=false EM stops always after 2 iterations, which does not look good... Btw, line 567 of semisupervised_naive_bayes.py seems to be executed in the case of relabel_all=false, however X_unlabeled is not defined since the condition of the if block in line 545 is not cleared. This seems like a bug of the original implementation, but I am not sure

Comment: @AM2 You're right, this seems to be a bug indeed. Do you have an idea about how to fix that?

Comment: I guess you could simply put all the contents within that if block outside, and remove the if. I am going to take closer look to the code in a few days and will post back again.  Btw, I also want EM for PU-Learning :)